# Is it possible to be charged for using the Google Analytics API, when using the free tier of Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics-api

From my understanding access to data via the API is free, but limited by a quota. However, a billing account is required.

Is anyone able to point to where this is stated explicitly? Or where it is contradicted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in your free $300 month you won't be charged for any reason if you run out of resources, you just won't be able to function and your account will suspend.  Once you activate your real account, with billing in place, anytime you breach the free-tier limits you'll automatically be billed.  It's not just quota, in some cases it's specific regions, like you can have one months of time worth of an f1-micro (i.e. 2 f1-micros you can have 2 weeks, etc) but only in the oregon, iowa, and south carolina regions.

The details on "Always Free" and the free trial can be found at 
[the Google Cloud Free Tier page](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that this is the case for the Google Cloud Free Tier. Is this also the case for calls to the Google Analytics Reporting API?  (only info on quotas I can find is [link] (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas) and does not contain pricing.

Comment: In general any api that has a free tier and a paid tier works that way; they're all under cloud services.  Looking at analytics however, I'm pretty sure those aren't free-tier quotas, those are request limits.  If you hit them you get errors.  You can request some be raised.  If you need more you can look at buy their premium Analytics 360 service which has fees.

Comment: The Google Reporting Analytics API quotas are here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas  you can request aditonal quota, they do not charge for this. It is separate from the cloud quota.

Comment: Thank you both for help!